# What is the chemistry of this household cleaning recipe?

Tags: acid-base, everyday-chemistry

What would be the product if baking soda and common salt and vinegar are added together?

Comment: A lot of the cleaning effect of this mixture is because of the sudden production of lots of CO2 bubbles that loosen and dislodge whatever it is you're trying to clean.

Answer (score 5):

Baking soda is sodium bicarbonate, and vinegar is dilute acetic acid. Common salt (table salt) is sodium chloride. Sodium bicarbonate will react with acetic acid to form sodium acetate (in solution), carbon dioxide gas, and water. Sodium chloride will not participate in the reaction. The reaction equation would be:

$$
\ce{NaHCO3(s) + HCH3COO(aq) -> NaCH3COO(aq) + CO2(g) + H2O(l)}
$$

Comment: The sodium chloride probably provides an abrasive.

Comment: @Ben It might - but it would need to be at a very high concentration for any to remain undissolved.